# Generate a dynamic report from POJO in BIRT

Tags: java, birt, dynamic-reports

I was wondering what's the best way to create a dynamic report from POJO(and not databases!) in BIRT. I'm new to BIRT, but I'm overwhelmed by the variety of information and no one go-to place for all the information. So, I'll be glad if anyone can suggest me the best way so that I can learn and build on it.

My program generates a POJO(let's call it report) that contains all the data to be published. Now, the BIRT should read this POJO and generate the report. The report contains several tables(say A,B,C...) and each table has its own structure(all this information is in the report). Since no aspect is static, I'm lost.

I read some tutorials, but they all explain from static(/mock) datasets or datasets retrieved from databases and don't explain many things like how to create columns on the fly....

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scripted data sets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Data_Access#Q%3a_How_do_I_get_data_from_a_POJO_.28Plain_Old_Java_Object.29.3F) are one way. Another is to create your own [ODA data source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Use_Case_-_Create_a_Custom_ODA_Data_Source). The latter is much more complicated, but better if you plan on reusing it frequently and need to access several different forms of data on the backend.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Could you tell me if I'd be needing DesignEngine API and all or can I get it done with scripting? I can't seem to understand the real purpose of DE API...

Comment: The DE API is great for writing your own designer (handles, change notification, etc) or programmatically creating reports (though the RE API can do that). To do it w/ scripting, just right click Data Sources in the Data Explorer and make a Scripted Data Source. Then right click the Data Sets and make a new data set under it. Define the fields and you will be presented with a script window right away. You should be able to follow the FAQ answer from there.

Comment: Hi Chad, I decided to go with custom ODA data sources to build the report. The whole process of report generation is easy, but I'm struck wondering how to build ODA from POJO. I looked everywhere but I couldn't find any good tutorial. They only explain how to create ODA from databases. They even don't have proper javadoc for that matter. Do you happen to know how to do it or any tutorial or place where I can find more information? Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/examples/scripting/scripteddatasource/

Answer (score 0):

BIRT can be daunting.  Don't feel bad.  I had to do something similar to what you are talking about last year.  Here are some references that were helpful to me.

http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/home/

They have forums at birt-exchange.  These seem to be read more by BIRT experts than a general site like StackOverflow.  You may have better luck getting specific answers there.

The book Integrating and Extending BIRT was also very useful.

[http://www.amazon.com/Integrating-Extending-BIRT-Jason-Weathersby/dp/0321443853](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321443853)

And last but not least, I recommend looking at the examples on Birt Exchange that produce graphs and reports that are similar to what you are trying to do.  It is much easier to figure out the patterns of usage from an example.

Good luck.